# Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using dispatch_async with Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, automatic-ref-counting, grand-central-dispatch

I have images in coredata which I'm trying to load lazily for a table view. Each cell uses an observer for the related core data entity to update the image when one becomes available.  The relevant code in the entity is as follows:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
  // The heavy lifting seems to be during firing of the fault and accessing data,
  // so i'm trying to do that in the background thread.
  UIImage *i = [UIImage imageWithData:self.imageEntity.data];
  // I now need to notify observers that the image is ready on the main thread
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"image"];
    image = i;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"image"];
  });
});
```

The project uses ARC, I'm not getting any compiler errors or warnings, and when I run it kind of works until I scroll fast, and then I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the line when i'm declaring the i.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you try with `NSZombieEnabled`?

Comment: what happen if you not using dispatch_async? just run on main thread

Comment: NSZombie doesn't shed any extra light for me. If I don't dispatch_async it'll block the main thread and scroll really poorly.

Comment: why dont you use nsoperationqueue...?

Comment: Not really sure how nsoperationqueue would be any different, I guess I'll try it if I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently fetching [CoreData objects is not thread safe](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html). So it's suggested to use the same persistentStoreCoordinator, but different ObjectContexts.  Here's my updated code that no longer seems to crash:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
  @autoreleasepool {
    // Create a new context
    NSManagedObjectContext *backgroundContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    // Use an existing coordinator
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [[DataSource sharedDataSource] persistentStoreCoordinator];
    [backgroundContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    // Getting objectID does not fire the fault, so we grab it but actually fetch the object
    // on a background context to be thread safe.
    Image *imageEntity = (Image*)[backgroundContext objectWithID:self.imageEntity.objectID];
    image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageEntity.data];
    // Notify observers that the image is ready on the main thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      [self willChangeValueForKey:@"image"];
      [self didChangeValueForKey:@"image"];
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you then save the image on the main thread, in the application managed object context? How would you do this, since it was created on the background thread?

Answer (score 1):

Dizy,  also keep in mind that the Image object that is created in the code:

```
UIImage *i = [UIImage imageWithData:self.imageEntity.data];
```

is set for autorelease.  The dispatch_async method runs on the main queue, so there is a chance that the memory allocated for the image may be released by the time the main thread runs the dispatch block.

Comment: Good point, do I just wrap the whole thing in @autoreleasepool {} to resolve that?

Comment: I would retain the image in the outer block then release it in the inner block.

Answer (score 0):

CoreData is not thread safe, you've to manage contexts to avoid crashes.
If you plan to heavy use a lot of concurrent processes to update data in Core Data, I would suggest you to take a look to [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord), an amazing pattern inspired by Active Record of Rails and that handles all these aspects in a really smart way.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out MagicalRecord, sounds pretty awesome.